# Edit Pivots while "Protect Workbook" is on in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a report file with two queries connected to my SQL database, along with several pivot tables. I want to share this report with a group of users, but I don't want them to have access to view or edit the queries.

I've tried using "Protect Workbook," which prevents them from editing the queries, but it also restricts their ability to edit sheets and pivot tables.

I also attempted "Protect Sheet," which allows me to specify how much access they have to edit, but unfortunately, it still permits them to view the queries.

Is there anyone who can assist me with this matter?

Comment: Can you clarify your question with what happens when you Protect the Workbook please. What's the main need to protect or hide the queries (SQL or Powerquery queries)?

Comment: By Protecting the workbook, users can't be able to edit "Queries and Connection" and they can't edit pivot tables for example they can't double-click on pivot records and see the related data in a new sheet, but they can refresh the sheets to see the update based on queries. We don't want to let users edit the queries and make changes to them while being able to edit pivots. we need just close the access to queries nothing more.

Comment: "Protect Workbook" does protect the queries and can let users create edit/new pivots. They **won't** be able to create new sheets or double-click on a pivot to get the data (as this creates a new sheet). If this really isn't an option, then 2 options come to mind. 1: Move all query logic to SQL Views or Stored Procedure and simply leave the workbook unprotected. 2: If you have Power BI then publish a Power BI dataset, and then have Excel connect to that, and then you'll have no need to protect since it is all in the PBI Dataset.

Comment: Thank you, the queries we prepared are a type of view, so it doesn't help and unfortunately, we have several reasons for not using Power BI.

Comment: did you consider using a third-party tool or add-ins that provide more granular control over user access to specific elements within the workbook?

Comment: Just curious - if queries are of Views, what's the reason for hiding/locking the queries? What scenario are you wanting to avoid? `SELECT * FROM View`.

Comment: It's a report for each salesperson that I prepared individually, so each user has their own file. Due to its importance and confidentiality, if they have access to the queries, they could potentially view sales details by making slight modifications to the query

Comment: Dear @JoyNa, I'm not familiar with these add-ins, could you please name some examples so I can find out which is more suitable?

Comment: I have done something similar by generating the queries dynamically in VBA. The VBA code is then password protected. It can be cracked but you could store the query on Protected sheets that are xlVeryHidden to obfuscate further. I'm off to find my tin-foil hat now :-)

Comment: This is so new to me, Thanks @CHill60 I'll try it